# How to check php script settings, locally in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I am running script with cURL operation in loop. Running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS local machine(not a server),`php -v = 5.6`  installed :
I run in in my terminal: `php myscript.php`,
script executes.Where I can check my php settings for running scripts? How to check and edit limits for my php scripts if they are already set?

----Edit----

```
~$ locate php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production.cli
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production.cli
```

Which one is correct one?

Comment: Maybe in `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current PHP settings for CLI run:

```
$ php -i
```

To change PHP settings  for CLI first found `php.ini` file path by running:

```
$ php -i | grep php.ini
```

You should get something like this, but with different paths:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

Find `php.ini` file from given path and this is PHP configuration file for CLI scripts.

Comment: What settings in `php.ini` should I set, if I want to execute my script to run forever?

Comment: You should set `max_execution_time = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can create phpinfo.php file in the same folder when you've got myscript.php.

inside phpinfo.php

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

and run php phpinfo.php it have to show you all informations + path to php.ini (there you can edit limits)